# Wie nennt man eine Gruppe Vogel Straußen

Tags: single-word-request, vocabulary, technical-terminology

Ich habe mich neulich gefragt, wie man eine Gruppe Vogel Strauße nennt. Ich habe mir gedacht, dass Schwarm, Rudel oder Herde möglich sind, bin mir aber nicht sicher und wollte daher gerne die Meinung Anderer einholen. Danke schon mal im Voraus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Diese Quelle](http://www.tierchenwelt.de/funfacts/tierbegriffe.html) sagt, man nennt einen aus Straußen bestehenden Tierverband *Herde*.

Auf den ersten Blick ist das plausibel, aber es wird keine Primärquelle dafür angegeben. Ist also möglicherweise mit Vorsicht zu genießen.

[Die Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrikanischer_Strau%C3%9F) spricht hingegen durchgängig von *Gruppe*, aber das ist kein Beweis, dass Herde falsch ist, sondern könnte auch einfach der Versuch einer vorsichtigen, allgemeinen Formulierung sein.

Answer (score 6):

*[Straußenherde](https://www.google.de/search?q=strau%C3%9Fenherde&biw=360&bih=615&prmd=mivn&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiqpewttvKAhVFPxoKHZJ8C-g4ChD8BQgHKAQ)* ist die gängige Bezeichnung für eine Gruppe von Straußen.

*Schwarm* wird für Gruppen **flugfähiger** Tiere (Vögel, Fledermäuse, Insekten...) sowie bei Fischen verwendet, wohingegen *Rudel* v.a. für Gruppen fleischfressender, jagender Säugetiere benutzt wird.